# Using Java/Lotus Script to determine if device is Touchscreen

Tags: java, lotusscript, touchscreen

Is there a way to determine if a device is a touchscreen device only using Java or Lotusscript? I haven't found any resources out there explaining how to determine, only with how to utilize commands from a touchscreen. Thank you.

Comment: Java is probably your better bet (and you can call Java from LS of course.)  Although Java's "write once-run anywhere" idea would likely abstract out exactly what kind of platform you're running on.  Is there a reason you need to know that the device has no mouse or physical keyboard?

Comment: It is for a electronic signature, so if there isn't a touchscreen, they need to use an electronic signature pad